# chat table summary list pgsql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have chat history table as below. where i will store from and to userIds.

**i am using Postgresql**

```
CREATE TABLE chat_history (
    chat_id serial,
    sender_id serial REFERENCES users(user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    recipient_id serial REFERENCES users(user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    message text NOT NULL,
    created_on TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    channel_id VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY key (chat_id),
    read_flag boolean
);
```

now i want to get the summary list of the user chat.
For ex: user1 - senderId = 1, user2 - recipientId = 2.

1. if these two users are chatting i need to pull the history. How to pull the history of the user
2. If an user has unread messages from multiple users how to get the summary list
   Like:
3. user1 to user2 => 5 unread message
4. user3 to user2 => 2 unread message
5. user5 to user2 => 2 unread message

I have tried the below query like

```
select  sender_id, recipient_id, count(*) from chat_history ch 
where (sender_id = 99 or recipient_id = 99) and (sender_id = 98 or recipient_id = 98)
and read_flag = false or read_flag = null
group by (sender_id, recipient_id, read_flag);
```

OutPut:

[image]

but it should return count = 4 irrespective of the sender and recipient Id

EDIT:
Tried below query

```
select distinct sender_id, recipient_id, count(*) from chat_history ch 
where (sender_id = 99 or recipient_id = 99) 
and read_flag = false or read_flag = null
group by (read_flag, sender_id, recipient_id);
```

but same out out

[image]

Adding live play ground: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4xvD4ZTPW2npKcy3Au92Y9/4

Comment: Hey, your CREATE-Statement does not match your query it misses the read_flag column. On top of that to reproduce your problem one would need the users table and some sample data, that demonstrates your problem. BTW: Check the _read_flag = null_ part of your query, this always yields FALSE. If checking for null in SQL use _is NULL_

Comment: AlexFunk, thank you for the input. i have added the read_flag in the question. let me know if there is any online environment where i can add few data and play with quires.

Comment: Why the `oracle`, `plsql` and `plsqldeveloper` tags if you are using Postgres? Those technologies have nothing to do with Postgres. Postgres uses PL/pgSQL to write stored procedures and functions, not PL/SQL. Please do not add tags for completely unrelated things

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, its all about the query. If any other developers come across this issue they can help me out so i added those tags.

Comment: The `sql` tag is enough for that.

Comment: @RavikumarK Something like that: [https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rpJGK8t6divrhCRkbGqJLE/0]

Comment: @AlexFunk https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4xvD4ZTPW2npKcy3Au92Y9/4

Comment: @RavikumarK better but what exactly do you expect as result from this data and why?

Comment: @AlexFunk, i want the summary of the chats for each user limit to 5. That summary may contain the unread messages or the messages user has sent to others. It should be latest summary. Sorry for the late reply power issue due to corona

Comment: @RavikumarK No problem, but still not sure, what you need. Do you need the 5 latest messages from each user, or from each conversation between two users? Maybe something like this?! https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4xvD4ZTPW2npKcy3Au92Y9/8

Comment: @AlexFunk, adding another fiddle [https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pR7iwoGmCMaLQVqFNjdE97/1]. in this i am getting 2 rows for the users 98 and 99. but its the same chat so i should get only 1 row out of it. I am keeping channel id as unique ID for each chat. do let me know if  you need more info on this

Comment: @AlexFunk, finally finished my query. can you tell is there any way i can do it efficiently, https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pR7iwoGmCMaLQVqFNjdE97/3

Answer (score 0):

Your db-fiddle and your problem description do not match.  You are asking for a couple of different things here.

**Query #1 addresses the example in your question**

```
    with all_ids as (
      select sender_id as user_id from chat_history
      union
      select recipient_id from chat_history
    )
    select i.user_id, count(*) as unread_sent_or_rcvd
      from chat_history h
      join all_ids i 
        on (i.user_id = h.sender_id or i.user_id = h.recipient_id)
     where coalesce(h.read_flag, false) = false
     group by i.user_id
     order by i.user_id;

| user_id | unread_sent_or_rcvd |
| ------- | ------------------- |
| 97      | 1                   |
| 98      | 48                  |
| 99      | 46                  |
```

**Query #2 addresses your problem statement**

I checked, and there is a record of `98` with an unread message to himself in his data.  He takes equal opportunity stalking to the next level.

```
    with all_ids as (
      select sender_id as user_id from chat_history
      union
      select recipient_id from chat_history
    )
    select i.user_id,
           case
              when i.user_id = h.sender_id then h.recipient_id
              else h.sender_id
           end as correspondent_id,
           count(*) filter (where i.user_id = h.sender_id) as unread_sent,
           count(*) filter (where i.user_id = h.recipient_id) as unread_rcvd
      from chat_history h
      join all_ids i 
        on (i.user_id = h.sender_id or i.user_id = h.recipient_id)
     where coalesce(h.read_flag, false) = false
     group by i.user_id, 
              case
                when i.user_id = h.sender_id then h.recipient_id
                else h.sender_id
              end
     order by i.user_id;

| user_id | correspondent_id | unread_sent | unread_rcvd |
| ------- | ---------------- | ----------- | ----------- |
| 97      | 98               | 1           | 0           |
| 98      | 97               | 0           | 1           |
| 98      | 98               | 1           | 1           |
| 98      | 99               | 44          | 2           |
| 99      | 98               | 2           | 44          |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4xvD4ZTPW2npKcy3Au92Y9/5)